# Print key and value for different entries in an object

Tags: json, jq

I need to print some results with jq to take json.
This is an example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": 20201606,
      "event": {
        "ip": "127.0.1",
        "hostname": "srv1",
        "locations": [
          "UK",
          "site1"
        ],
        "num": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "time": 202016034,
      "event": {
        "ip": "127.0.2",
        "hostname": "srv2",
        "locations": [
          "UK",
          "site2"
        ],
        "num": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Like to generate this output "num, ip, hostname, locations":

```
1, srv1, 127.0.1, UK,site1
2, srv2, 127.0.2, HK,site2
3, srv3, 127.0.3, LO,site3
```

How can I print this via jq?

Answer (score 3):

Join locations by a comma, and put the result into an array with other fields. Then join again by a comma followed by a space to get the desired output format. E.g.:

```
.data[].event | [
  .num,
  .hostname,
  .ip,
 (.locations | join(",")) ?
] | join(", ")
```

Use `--raw-output`/`-r` option in the command line invocation to get raw strings instead of JSON strings.

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5TqoVDG_Eq)</sup>

Comment: i update the original post because I forget the "data": [" value

Answer (score 1):

At its core, you want to build an array consisting of the values you want:

```
$ jq '.data[].event | [.num, .hostame, .ip, .locations]' tmp.json
[
  1,
  null,
  "127.0.1",
  [
    "UK",
    "site1"
  ]
]
[
  3,
  null,
  "127.0.2",
  [
    "UK",
    "site2"
  ]
]
```

From there, it's a matter of formatting. First, let's turn the list of locations into a single string:

```
$ jq '.data[].event | [.num, .hostame, .ip, (.locations|join(","))]' tmp.json
[
  1,
  null,
  "127.0.1",
  "UK,site1"
]
[
  3,
  null,
  "127.0.2",
  "UK,site2"
]
```

Next, let's join *those* strings into a `", "`-separated string.

```
$ jq '.data[].event | [.num, .hostame, .ip, (.locations|join(","))] | join(", ")' tmp.json
"1, , 127.0.1, UK,site1"
"3, , 127.0.2, UK,site2"
```

Finally, you can use the `-r` flag to output raw text rather than a JSON string value.

```
$ jq -r '.data[].event | [.num, .hostame, .ip, (.locations|join(","))] | join(", ")' tmp.json
1, , 127.0.1, UK,site1
3, , 127.0.2, UK,site2
```

Comment: I update the original post because I forget the ""data": [" value

Comment: seems better! but it's possible to control if locations is null? If I have this "locations": null, the array fails...

Comment: Any other surprise changes to the input?